# Searching for entities through EF6 where field is null produces incorrect results

Tags: linq, null, entity-framework-6

I am trying to pull data from my database through EF6. I want all of the rejected or approved tickets that have a TicketProcessStatus of null. I expect 11 tickets that meet those criteria, but I am getting the rejected and approved tickets that have non-null TicketProcessStatus values. How should I set up the where clause?

```
public IEnumerable<TEntity> FindBy(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{            
    IEnumerable<TEntity> results = _dbSet.AsNoTracking().Where(predicate).ToList();
    return results;
}
```

Attempt #1

```
var closeables = unitOfWorkCraw.Tickets
    .FindBy(w => w.TicketProcessStatus == null &&
            (w.TicketStatus.Equals(TicketStatus.APPROVED) 
            || w.TicketStatus.Equals(TicketStatus.REJECTED)));
```

Attempt #2

```
string MrNull = null;
var closeables = unitOfWorkCraw.Tickets
    .FindBy(w => object.Equals(w.TicketProcessStatus, MrNull) &&
            (w.TicketStatus.Equals(TicketStatus.APPROVED) 
            || w.TicketStatus.Equals(TicketStatus.REJECTED)));
```

Attempt #3

```
var closeables = unitOfWorkCraw.Tickets
    .FindBy(w => string.IsNullOrEmpty(w.TicketProcessStatus) &&
            (w.TicketStatus.Equals(TicketStatus.APPROVED) 
            || w.TicketStatus.Equals(TicketStatus.REJECTED)));
```

An example of what is coming back:

- Ticket #1:: TicketStatus: Approved, TicketProcessStatus: Success
- Ticket #2:: TicketStatus: Rejected, TicketProcessStatus: Success
- Ticket #3:: TicketStatus: Rejected, TicketProcessStatus: *[NULL]*
- Ticket #4:: TicketStatus: Approved, TicketProcessStatus: *[NULL]*

Only tickets #3 and #4 should be returned.

Comment: Try putting brackets around the "or" statements so they are grouped, as in `condition one && (condition 2 || condition 3)`. E.g. `string.IsNullOrEmpty(w.TicketProcessStatus) &&
            (w.TicketStatus.Equals(TicketStatus.APPROVED) 
            || w.TicketStatus.Equals(TicketStatus.REJECTED))`. Attempt #3 should work given `TicketProcessStatus` is of string type.

Comment: I am not sure why that didn't make it into my post.  Edited to include proper groupings.

Comment: `TicketProcessStatus` is a string? Also, by "**I am getting the rejected and approved tickets that have non-null TicketProcessStatus values**", could you give an example or 2 about which strings/objects got through the conditions?

Comment: Sure. No problem